# swift performance issue: local array vs global array

Tags: ios, arrays, performance, swift

I found a strange performance issue when playing with array in swift.

In the following two demo codes, I try to do a random copy for an array.
The only difference between these two codes is the position of the array definition.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var array: [Int] = [] /* HERE */
        var n: Int = 10000
        var timer = NSDate()
        for i in 0 ..< n {
            array.append(i)
        }
        println("append \(n) elements \(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timer))")
        for i in 0 ..< n {
            var p: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count - i))) + i
            array[i] = array[p]
        }
        println("permutation \(array.count) elements \(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timer))")
    }
}
// append 10000 elements 0.0597179532051086
// permutation 10000 elements 0.108937978744507
```

But when I move the definition of array outside the function (inside the class), then some strange things happened.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var array: [Int] = [] /* HERE */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var n: Int = 10000
        var timer = NSDate()
        for i in 0 ..< n {
            array.append(i)
        }
        println("append \(n) elements \(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timer))")
        for i in 0 ..< n {
            var p: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count - i))) + i
            array[i] = array[p]
        }
        println("permutation \(array.count) elements \(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(timer))")
    }
}
// append 10000 elements 0.0645599961280823
// permutation 10000 elements 4.61092203855515
```

I am a newbie to swift. But I guess I am familiar with other programming language such C++, Java, Python. And this behaviour is REALLY REALLY strange for me. Am I miss anything?

Thanks so much for your help. :>

> BTW, my XCode version is 6.1 6A1052D, and the simulator is iPad. I use Debug mode to test my code. But even in Release mode, the second code is still much slower than the first one. So Sad. ;<

Comment: I posted this issue on Apple developer's forum. People told me that  I should declare the array use "final" keyword to improve the performance issue (and it's currently a known bug, I guess Apple's engineer will fix it latter). For more details, please check https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, the results change dramatically if you replace:

```
for i in 0 ..< n {
    let p = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count - i))) + i
    array[i] = array[p]
}
```

with

```
for i in 0 ..< n {
    let p = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count - i))) + i
    let tmp = array[p]
    array[i] = tmp
}
```

Comment: Wow, I tried your code, and it works! BTW, what's wrong with the first one? I cannot understand that. :<

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with the code, IMHO. I think the problem is in Swift's array handling. It must be trying to handle contention issues by copying the array before adjusting it, or something curious like that. Seems worthy of a bug report, but let's see if anyone else chimes in with any interesting findings...

Comment: Agree. I guess maybe I should also post this issue on Apple's forum. Thanks.